# How can i simplify the new sessions i create for a model which is linked?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a login action in my control. Sessions are created for Auth.User, but not for Auth.Town. I need to create sessions. I have several fields in the towns table, and I do not want to create 50 lines. How can i make it easier ? i need to simplify it .

UsersController :

```
    public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if (isset($this->request->data['UserLogin'])) {
            $this->request->data['User'] = $this->request->data['UserLogin'];
     } 

        if ($this->Auth->login()) {

            $this->Session->write(
                        'Auth.Town.name',
                        $this->User->Town->field('name')
                );

            $this->Session->write(
                        'Auth.Town.country',
                        $this->User->Town->field('country')
                );

            $this->Session->write(
                        'Auth.Town.localisation',
                        $this->User->Town->field('localisation')
                );

            $this->Session->write(
                        'Auth.Town.statut',
                        $this->User->Town->field('statut')
                );


                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect()); 

            }else{

                $this->Session->setFlash("L'adresse électronique ou votre mot de passe ne correspond pas","notif",array('type'=>'error'));

            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just get the columns, then loop and assignment:

```
$towns = array('name', 'country', 'localisation', 'statut');
foreach($towns as $column) {
    $this->Session->write(
        'Auth.Town.' . $column,
        $this->User->Town->field($column)
    );
}
```

Comment: You should have in mind that `Model::field()` issues a separate SQL query per call, so that's very inefficient. Also the authentication adapters do support including associations using `contain`, and by default they are using a `recursive` setting of `0`, so `belongsTo` and `hasOne` associations (pretty sure `Town` uses one of those) should be included by default.

Answer (score 1):

As i checked

```
$this->Session->read('Auth.User.Town.name');
```

must be having the name you want to have